# Use overlay to show lists of location in mapView

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps

I have a list of address, however, I don't have the actual longitude and latitude of those address.
Any methods to convert address to long. and lat. , and then save in mysql database
Then, when I　go to the mapview, it get the list of long. & lat. in mysql and show in mapview
I am new to android so please help me to solve^^

Answer (score 1):

You need Forward Geocoding
Forward geocoding (or just geocoding) determines map coordinates for a given location.

here is the example

//this is snippet of getting geolocation

```
List<Address> result = geocoder.getFromLocationName(aStreetAddress, maxResults);
Geocoder fwdGeocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.US);
String streetAddress = “160 Riverside Drive, New York, New York”;
```

.......................................................................
How to do this...

```
List<Address> locations = null;
 try {
locations = fwdGeocoder.getFromLocationName(streetAddress, 10);
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Where 10 is the maximum results because there can me more than one location of same name.
This will simply return the lat and lang(geo points)

After getting the list of latitude and longitude add them in database.

Comment: In addition add the code above in loop that will go over each address in your list with one for loop :)

Comment: but actually just need to convert the address to Gpoint once, so you recommend to use this^^?

Comment: ya but if you want more locations points , iterate through the addresses.